# Chemical formulas with Mathematica

Tags: code-request, chemistry

I am aware that there are many many things that we can do in Mathematica, but I am wondering if it is also possible to construct chemical compunds such as for example the one below?:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Using @MarcoB suggestions I get the following:

`MoleculePlot@ Molecule["FC1=CC(F)=C(C2OCC(COC3=CC=C(N4CCN(C5=CC=C(N6C=NN(C(C(O)C)\ CC)C6=O)C=C5)CC4)C=C3)C2CN7C=NC=N7)C=C1"]`

which gives:

[image]

Why are some molecules red and some others blue? Is there a way to control the color so that all are black for example?

Another possibility I just found was to used something simple like:

`MoleculePlot@Molecule["C37H42F2N8O4"]`

which gives:

[image]

In this case, it also gives me automatically different colors for each molecule and also additionally the bonds out and in plane. How can I make normal bonds and tune the color?

Comment: What do you mean by construct? If you want to *draw* chemical structures, then the industry standards are ChemDraw or similar programs. Have you seen the [Molecular structure and computation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MolecularStructureAndComputation.html) guide?

Comment: Something like this? `MoleculePlot@ Molecule["FC1=CC(F)=C(C2OCC(COC3=CC=C(N4CCN(C5=CC=C(N6C=NN(C(C(O)C)CC)C6=O)C=C5)CC4)C=C3)C2CN7C=NC=N7)C=C1"]`

Comment: If you have version 12.2 you can try `MoleculeDraw@MoleculeRecognize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL8dr.png"]`

Comment: @MarcoB I am aware of ChemDraw but I was just wondering about the capabilities of Mathematica regarding this. Your code is great by the way

Comment: @JasonB. I have the version 12.1 and it looks like it gets the formula but I am not sure how to get it like in a picture or Tiff

Comment: You can use `MoleculePlot[Molecule["FC1=CC(F)=C(C2OCC(COC3=CC=C(N4CCN(C5=CC=C(N6C=NN(C(C(O)C)CC)C6=O)C=C5)CC4)C=C3)C2CN7C=NC=N7)C=C1"], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]` if you want a BW picture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Assuming that you are starting with a chemical formula

```
Interpreter["Chemical"]["C37H42F2N8O4"] // InputForm

(* Entity["Chemical", "Posaconazole"] *)
```

Several forms of diagrams are available:

```
Entity["Chemical", "Posaconazole"][#] & /@ {"BlackStructureDiagram", 
   "CHBlackStructureDiagram", "ColorStructureDiagram", 
   "CHColorStructureDiagram", "LewisDotStructureDiagram", "MoleculePlot", 
   "StickMoleculePlot", "SpaceFillingMoleculePlot"} // Column
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To increase (double) the font size

```
Entity["Chemical", "Posaconazole"]["BlackStructureDiagram"] /. 
 Rule[FontSize, Scaled[s_]] :> Rule[FontSize, Scaled[2 s]]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob Hanlon what a fantastic program Mathematica is! Thank you for this. One quick questions if you don't mind. Do you know if it is possible to make the molecules a little bit bigger (change the font of the molecules)? I am accepting your answer. Thanks

Comment: Use `ImageSize` with `Show` to change the size of the diagram: `Show[diagram, ImageSize -> Large]`. I do not know how to just change the `FontSize`.